Module not found / build failed in my yarn workspaces monorepo
I am combining my React web application with my Expo React Native mobile app into a monorepo using yarn workspaces because they both need to share some utils, queries, etc. My file structure is something like this:
- ui
    - apps
        - mobile
            - package.json
        - web
            - package.json
    - packages
        - shared
            - package.json
    - package.json
    - node_modules

Mobile works fine with Expo but when I try running my web code, I get this:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'crypto' in 'ui/node_modules/expo-modules-core/build/uuid'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "crypto": require.resolve("crypto-browserify") }'
    - install 'crypto-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "crypto": false }

Module build failed (from ../../node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: ui/node_modules/expo-router/build/ExpoRoot.js: Support for the experimental syntax 'jsx' isn't currently enabled (54:17):

  52 |      */
  53 |     const wrapper = ({ children }) => {
> 54 |         return (<ParentWrapper>
     |                 ^
  55 |         <react_native_safe_area_context_1.SafeAreaProvider 
  56 |         // SSR support
  57 |         initialMetrics={INITIAL_METRICS}>

Add @babel/preset-react (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-preset-react) to the 'presets' section of your Babel config to enable transformation.
If you want to leave it as-is, add @babel/plugin-syntax-jsx (https://github.com/babel/babel/tree/main/packages/babel-plugin-syntax-jsx) to the 'plugins' section to enable parsing.

If you already added the plugin for this syntax to your config, it's possible that your config isn't being loaded.
You can re-run Babel with the BABEL_SHOW_CONFIG_FOR environment variable to show the loaded configuration:
    npx cross-env BABEL_SHOW_CONFIG_FOR=ui/node_modules/expo-router/build/ExpoRoot.js <your build command>
See https://babeljs.io/docs/configuration#print-effective-configs for more info.

I've tried everything and nothing seems to fix this.
For the first error, I have only been able to fix it using react-app-rewired and adding a fallback for the 'crypto' module as a config override, but I'd rather avoid having to rely on react-app-rewired if there is a better solution
For the second one, I already have the babel preset as you can see in my babel.config.json in ui/apps/web and it still doesn't work
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "@babel/preset-env",
      {
        "targets": {
          "edge": "17",
          "firefox": "60",
          "chrome": "67",
          "safari": "11.1"
        },
        "useBuiltIns": "usage",
        "corejs": "3.6.5"
      }
    ],
    "@babel/preset-react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx"]
}

For reference, these are my package.json(s):
    // ui/package.json    
        {
          "private": true,
          "name": "monorepo",
          "version": "1.0.0",
          "workspaces": [
            "apps/*",
            "packages/*"
          ]
        }


MOBILE

{
  "name": "monorepo-mobile",
  "main": "index.js",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "reset-project": "node ./scripts/reset-project.js",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "expo lint"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.2",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.24.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.51.1",
    "@monorepo/shared": "*",
    "axios": "^1.7.2",
    "expo": "~51.0.20",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.8",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-localization": "~15.0.3",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.18",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "i18next": "^23.12.1",
    "nativewind": "^2.0.11",
    "react": "18.3.1",
    "react-dom": "18.3.1",
    "react-i18next": "^14.1.2",
    "react-native": "0.74.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-heroicons": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "^15.4.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~51.0.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.3.1",
    "tailwindcss": "3.3.2",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}


WEB

    // ui/apps/web/package.json
    {
      "name": "autoguardias-web",
      "version": "0.1.0",
      "private": true,
      "proxy": "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
      "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
        "@headlessui/react": "^1.7.18",
        "@heroicons/react": "^2.0.16",
        "@mui/material": "^5.12.1",
        "@react-pdf/renderer": "^3.3.8",
        "@tanstack/react-query": "^4.29.7",
        "@tanstack/react-query-devtools": "^4.29.7",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
        "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
        "axios": "^1.3.4",
        "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
        "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
        "chart.js": "^4.4.3",
        "chartjs-adapter-moment": "^1.0.1",
        "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^3.0.1",
        "clsx": "^1.2.1",
        "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
        "i18next": "^23.4.1",
        "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^7.1.0",
        "install": "^0.13.0",
        "moment": "^2.30.1",
        "npm": "^10.1.0",
        "react": "^18.3.1",
        "react-calendly": "^4.1.1",
        "react-chartjs-2": "^5.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.3.1",
        "react-i18next": "^13.0.3",
        "react-joyride": "^2.7.2",
        "react-number-format": "^5.1.4",
        "react-pdf": "^7.7.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.8.2",
        "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
        "react-spring": "^9.7.1",
        "react-tooltip": "^5.22.0",
        "react-youtube": "^10.1.0",
        "uuid": "^9.0.0",
        "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
      },
      "engines": {
        "node": ">=12.0.0"
      },
      "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "lint": "eslint \"src/**/*.js\"",
        "lintfix": "eslint --fix \"src/**/*.js\"",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "build:staging": "env-cmd -f .env.staging npm run build"
      },
      "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": [
          "react-app",
          "react-app/jest"
        ]
      },
      "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
          "last 1 chrome version",
          "last 1 firefox version",
          "last 1 safari version"
        ]
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.22.5",
        "@babel/core": "^7.22.5",
        "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.22.5",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx": "^7.22.5",
        "@babel/plugin-syntax-typescript": "^7.22.5",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.22.5",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.22.5",
        "@tailwindcss/forms": "^0.5.3",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.13",
        "eslint": "^8.42.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^19.0.4",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.27.5",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.7.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.6.0",
        "postcss": "^8.4.21",
        "tailwindcss": "^3.2.7"
      }
    }


SHARED

    // ui/packages/shared/package.json
    {
      "name": "@monorepo/shared",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "main": "index.js",
      "license": "MIT",
      "dependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.7",
        "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.51.1",
        "expo-router": "~3.5.18",
        "axios": "^1.7.2",
        "i18next": "^23.11.5",
        "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^8.0.0",
        "react-i18next": "^14.1.2",
        "react-native": "0.74.3",
        "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.24.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.24.7"
      }
    }

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance
